# Connected flexible 2 x 2 white plates - what set?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, piece-information

I'm going through my old Lego collection and trying to identify the original sets they're from. The bulk of the Lego is from the 70s and 80s.

I have a piece that is two white 2 x 2 plates joined together by a thin cord. I seem to remember it joined a car to a cart or something like that, but I can't find the part in any of the sites I've looked.

Can anyone help me with this piece (either how to properly describe it when searching catalogues or possible sets it may be from).

[image: FourByFourJoined]

Answer (score 9):

That's an old [650 Hinge Coupling Nylon - Two Connected 2 x 2 Plates](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=650) from the 60s.

[image]

It only ever came in [20 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=650&in=S), but it's typically clear. It's listed as a possible alternate for the following set, but it's possible other sets could have had it as an alternate too.

[901-2 2 Large Wheels with Accessories](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=901-2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me with this piece (either how to properly describe it when searching catalogues...)

When searching *[Bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70849-1&name=Wyld-Mayhem%20Star%20Fighter&category=%5BThe%20LEGO%20Movie%202%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22cond%22:%22N%22,%22loc%22:%22US%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)* the syntax is specific too. It only comes up as:
"`2 x 2 plates`"

*2[space]x[space]2[space]plate(s)*

Anything different like typing only the singular word "plate", and you'll get no hits.

Comment: I suspect the bigger problem is that the OP referred to them as "4 x 4 plates" rather than "2 x 2 plates"

Comment: @ Dave. I agree with and approved both your edits.  I gave you edit rights to my entry, but it looks like other users will have to collectively agree with us to change the OP's words, unless he does it himself. Thanks for further smoothing out the syntax of my post.

Comment: it seems 2 different Davids have been involved here; I commented but did not suggest any edits!

Comment: @Dave to further confuse things two different Davids both with green identicons!

Comment: Guys, you can type 2x2 *without* spaces and it will still work.